# How many page-table entries are needed in case the program uses the whole logical address space

Tags: memory, bitwise-operators, paging, page-tables

Say I have:

- page size = 2^12 bytes
- physical memory = 2^24 bytes
- logical address space = 2^32

How many page-table entries are needed in case the program uses the whole logical address space?

I have found so far that the inner offset is 12 bits while the page number part inside the logical address is 20 bits.

*Is the answer 2^20 correct?*